# How to add Android support to my Ionic app project?

Tags: node.js, eclipse, cordova, ionic-framework, npm-install

I have created an Ionic app project. I want to add Android support to my app. For that I used "ionic platform add Android. But my system shows some errors. I am using a windows machine. The errors showing in cmd is

```
    Adding android project...

Running command: cmd "/s /c "C:\Users\SYSTEM-03\.cordova\lib\npm_cache\cordova-android\6.0.0\package\bin\create.bat E:\workspace\appstore\demoapp\platforms\android com.ionicframework.demoapp722446 demoapp --cli""

C:\Users\SYSTEM-03\.cordova\lib\npm_cache\cordova-android\6.0.0\package\bin\templates\cordova\lib\AndroidStudio.js:16
    for(file of eclipseFiles) {
             ^^
SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier
    at Module._compile (module.js:439:25)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:474:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:356:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:312:12)
    at Module.require (module.js:364:17)
    at require (module.js:380:17)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\SYSTEM-03\.cordova\lib\npm_cache\cordova-android\6.0.0\package\bin\templates\cordova\lib\AndroidProject.js:24:21)
    at Module._compile (module.js:456:26)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:474:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:356:32)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to install java with required version and Android studio. Set the path in the environment variables for both java and android studio.

Follow these steps

**Requirements**

In order to install ionic framework, we should have the following requirements. It supports iOS 6+, Android 4.0+.
Node.js
Apache Cordova
Ionic
Git
Java JDK
Apache Ant
Android Studio
Google Chrome Canary (Optional)

Steps in Windows OS
Download and install Node.js from this. (Here node.js is an executable file)

Install Cordova
Use the below command to install cordova. (npm is a node.js related command)

```
C:\ npm install -g cordova
```

Install iconic

```
C:\ npm install -g ionic
```

Install Git
Download and install Git from this. Choose “Run Git from the Windows Command Prompt” option while installing. Git will be used when we want to install cordova plugins from github (.git files).

Install JDK, Apache Ant, Android Studio
Install most recent Java JDK (not just JRE) from this
Create an environmental variable for JAVA_HOME pointing to java JDK root folder.

```
C:\ set JAVA_HOME=“C:\Program Files\Java\jdk7”
```

Add JDK’s bin to the PATH environmental variable

```
C:\ set PATH=%PATH%;“C:\Program Files\Java\jdk7\bin”
```

Download Apache Ant from this.
Extract it to the `C:\ directory`
Add Ant’s bin to the PATH environmental variable

```
C:\ set PATH=%PATH%;“C:\apache-ant-1.9.2\bin”
```

Download Android Studio from this.
Install Android Studio
Open `“Android SDK Manager”` from Android Studio “Configure” option
Select following packages.
Android SDK Tools
Android SDK Platform-tools
Android SDK Build-tools for Revision 20 & 19
Android 6.0 (API 23)
Android 4.4W.2 (API 20)
Android 4.4.2 (API 19)
Android Support Library (From Extras)
Click on `“Install Packages”` and accept license for all packages.
Cordova requires the ANDROID_HOME environmental variable to set.

```
C:\ set ANDROID_HOME=“C:\android\sdk”
```

Update PATH variable to include `tools/ and platform-tools/` folder in that folder.

```
C:\ set PATH=%PATH%;%ANDROID_HOME%\tools
        C:\ set PATH=%PATH%;%ANDROID_HOME%\platform-tools
```

Create Ionic project
    We can create Cordova-Ionic project somewhere on the computer.
C:\ ionic start  [blank/tabs/sidemenu/maps]
C:\ cd

Ionic command line features:
a. start:
   c:> ionic start myproj blank
     Creates ionic project in the in which directory you have run this command.

b. serve:
   c:\myproj> ionic serve
     Starts local development server to run the project.

c. platform:
   c:\myproj> ionic platform add android
     Configure cordova for desired platform android or ios.

d. build:
   c:\myproj> ionic build android
Build executes a local build for the platform which we specify. This creates CordovaApp-debug.apk file in c:\myproj\platforms\android\ant-build location.

e. emulate:
   c:\myproj> ionic emulate android
     Starts the app in specified platform

f. run:
   c:\myproj> ionic run android
     Deploys and runs the app on the actual mobile device

g.  Install IOS emulator test ios build in windows machine
   c:\ npm install -g ios-sim

Comment: Thanks for help it worked..problem is android path didnt set correctly in cmd